# s3 video not always playing on chrome but works on firefox

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-s3, html5-video

I have a landing page video that I downloaded from vimeo and am storing in an s3 account. I am using regular video tag to display the video. Everything works on firefox but the majority of the time it doesn't load in chrome. I dug around and found it might be an encoding problem but I know very little about encoding and can't seem to find details on what the video should be encoded as. I was hoping someone has encountered a similar problem or could advise me on what the video might need to be encoded as.

```
<video style={{ objectFit: 'cover', width: '100%', height: '100%', top: '50%', position: 'relative', transform: 'translateY(-50%)' }} loop autoPlay>
    <source src="https://momentum-engineer.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/4.13+main+page+(1).mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out chrome will only auto play a video if it is muted. I had to add the following items to get the video to play on load:

```
<video loop autoPlay muted playsInline ....
```